# Is Knative the successor to Skaffold

Tags: knative-serving

Is Knative the successor to Skaffold and can you briefly tell what the difference is between Skaffold and Knative?

Thanks
Regards
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knative is a "Kubernetes-based platform to build, deploy, and manage modern serverless workloads". Details [here](https://www.knative.dev/)

"Skaffold handles the workflow for building, pushing and deploying your application". Details [here](https://skaffold.dev/)

i.e. you could use Skaffold to redeploy your Knative application when you save any changes instead of manually having to apply any changes to Knative/Kubernetes every time you make a change.